# Pronunciation of "How are they?"

Tags: pronunciation

Is it true that we pronounce it as:

**"How A they"**

And we miss **"re"**?

Comment: Only if you speak like New Englanders who drop "r" when they speak.

Comment: Generally in BrE the **R** sound is much softer than that in, say Spanish, and is almost a different consonant to the French **R**. Many speakers will pronounce the **R** in "are", some won't sound it at all: like "How ah they?"

Comment: Thank you guys, @WeatherVane with  "How ah they?" it's clear to me but I can't hear "h" sound anyway!

Comment: @WorldLiver, what are you listening to? Where's the speaker from?

Comment: @WorldLover The 'h' in 'ah' is silent. It is there to make the pronunciation sound like the interjection spelled "ah", rather than like the indefinite article "a".

Comment: It wasn't clear what was meant by **A**. I meant as in **[ɑː] start, father**, I pronounce **are** like I say **start**. No **R** is heard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **non-rhotic** accents,  the *R sound* is not pronounced unless it comes before a vowel sound.

**For example:** Are -> /ɑː/ (no **R** sound because there is no vowel sound after **R**).

Brother -> /b**r**ʌðə/ (it does have **R** sound because there is a vowel sound after **R**).

On the other hand,  speakers of  **rhotic** accents pronounce their R's. ([Rhoticity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhoticity_in_English))

**Example:** Speakers of rhotic accents might pronounce 'are' as /ɑːr/ (with **R** sound).

In 'are they', the /r/ sound precedes a consonant sound /ð/ (th), so the R sound is not pronounced (non-rhotic accents).

Speakers of rhotic accents might pronounce 'are they' with /r/ sound.

☆RP (Standard British accent) is non-rhotic while General American accent is rhotic.